# Can I save part of the post in an external file and join it on the fly to avoid redundancy in the wp_posts table?

Tags: posts, text

To start with, I apologise if this is a double, which I believe is the case, but searching for similar posts is not easy.

In my blog, I will have a lot of posts(more than 1000 at one stage) where the only change between these posts is data.

The content - made up of heavy HTML - will be the same.

A good example - although my HTML will be bigger - is:

[image: a busy cat]

... where the only difference between posts are the values.

Now I know I can save the same HTML for every post I publish, but is there a more efficient way of doing it in order NOT to save the same HTML over and over again in the wp_posts table?

It would be such a big waste in my opinion.

What I thought so far is that I can:

a. Keep the empty HTML in - let's say - a text file with dummy data

b. In the post I save only the data, so if we are to use the above image as an example, I save 1.9|0.003|40%

 and 
1.7|0.002|43%

c. In the single.php file, on the fly that is, I get the HTML from the text file, the data from the post and I merge them by manipulating the pipe-delimited string

Does it make sense and if yes, is my way of doing it the best way? Or maybe I should keep the HTML in the database, in a custom table maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider using your own table [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) with data input but renders the html tables with the data?

Comment: Brilliant - just what I needed birgire, was not aware of shortcodes. Thanks!

Comment: I've one example of a [table shortcode on github](https://github.com/birgire/wp-table-shortcode), that's hopefully helpful.

Comment: Perhaps someone should write that out as an answer so it can be accepted, in more detail